# Split a column in a text file

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a system which generates 3 text (.txt) files on a daily basis, with 1000's of entries within each.

Once the text files are generated we run a vbscript (below) that modifies the files by entering data at specific column positions.

I now need this vbscript to do an additional task which is to separate a column in one of the text files.

So for example the TR201501554s.txt file looks like this:

```
6876786786  GFS8978976        I
6786786767  DDF78676          I
4343245443  SBSSK67676        I
8393372263  SBSSK56565        I
6545434347  DDF7878333        I
6757650000  SBSSK453          I
```

With the additional task of seperating the column, data will now look like this, with the column seperated at a specific position.

```
6876786786  GFS    8978976      I
6786786767  DDF    78676        I
4343245443  SBSSK  67676        I
8393372263  SBSSK  56565        I
6545434347  DDF    7878333      I
6757650000  SBSSK  453          I
```

I was thinking maybe I could add another "case" to accomplish this with maybe using a "regex" pattern, since the pattern would be only 3 companies to find 
(DDF, GFS and SBSSK).

But after looking at many examples, I am not really sure where to start.

Could someone let me know how to accomplish this additional task in our vbscript (below)?

```
Option Explicit
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2


Dim objFSO, pFolder, cFile, objWFSO, objFileInput, objFileOutput,strLine
Dim strInputPath, strOutputPath , sName, sExtension
Dim strSourceFileComplete, strTargetFileComplete, objSourceFile, objTargetFile
Dim iPos, rChar
Dim fileMatch


'folder paths
strInputPath = "C:\Scripts\Test"
strOutputPath = "C:\Scripts\Test"

'Create the filesystem object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get a reference to the processing folder
Set pFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strInputPath)

'loop through the folder and get the file names to be processed
For Each cFile In pFolder.Files
ProcessAFile cFile
Next

Sub ProcessAFile(objFile)
fileMatch = false

Select Case Left(objFile.Name,2)
    Case "MV"
        iPos = 257
        rChar = "YES"
        fileMatch = true
    Case "CA"
        iPos = 45
        rChar = "OCCUPIED"
        fileMatch = true
    Case "TR"
        iPos = 162
        rChar = "EUR"
        fileMatch = true
End Select

If fileMatch = true Then

    Set objWFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFileInput = objWFSO.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path, ForReading)
    strSourceFileComplete = objFile.Path
    sExtension = objWFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)
    sName = Replace(objFile.Name, "." & sExtension, "")

    strTargetFileComplete = strOutputPath & "\" & sName & "_mod." & sExtension
    Set objFileOutput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strTargetFileComplete, ForWriting, True) 

        Do While Not objFileInput.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFileInput.ReadLine
        If Len(strLine) >= iPos Then
            objFileOutput.WriteLine(Left(strLine,iPos-1) & rChar)
        End If

    Loop
    objFileInput.Close
    objFileOutput.Close
    Set objFileInput = Nothing
    Set objFileOutput = Nothing

    Set objSourceFile = objWFSO.GetFile(strSourceFileComplete)
    objSourceFile.Delete
    Set objSourceFile = Nothing

    Set objTargetFile = objWFSO.GetFile(strTargetFileComplete)
    objTargetFile.Move strSourceFileComplete    
    Set objTargetFile = Nothing
    Set objWFSO = Nothing
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What's the exact problem with the code you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wzad2b2%28v=vs.84%29) [replacement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to your input processing loop. Since you want to re-format the columns I'd do it with a [replacement function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974619.aspx#scripting12_topic4). Define both the regular expression and the function in the global scope:

```
...
Set pFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strInputPath)

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "  ([A-Z]+)(\d+)( +)"

Function ReFormatCol(m, g1, g2, g3, p, s)
  ReFormatCol = Left("  " & Left(g1 & "    ", 7) & g2 & g3, Len(m)+2)
End Function

'loop through the folder and get the file names to be processed
For Each cFile In pFolder.Files
...
```

and modify the input processing loop like this:

```
...
Do While Not objFileInput.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = re.Replace(objFileInput.ReadLine, GetRef("ReFormatCol"))
  If Len(strLine) >= iPos Then
    objFileOutput.WriteLine(Left(strLine,iPos-1) & rChar)
  End If
Loop
...
```

Note that you may need to change your `iPos` values, since splitting and re-formatting the columns increases the length of the lines by 2 characters.

The callback function `ReFormatCol` has the following (required) parameters:

- `m`: the match of the regular expression (used to determine the length of the match)
- `g1`, `g2`, `g3`: the three groups from the expression
- `p`: the starting position of the match in the source string (but not used here)
- `s`: the source string (but not used here)

The function constructs the replacement for the match from the 3 groups like this:

- `Left(g1 & "    ", 7)` appends 4 spaces to the first group (e.g. `GFS`) and trims it to 7 characters. This is based on the assumption that the first group will always be 3-5 characters long.
  →  `GFS`
- `"  " & ... & g2 & g3` prepends the result of the above operation with 2 spaces and appends the other 2 groups (`8978976` &         ).
  →   `GFS    8978976`
- `Left(..., Len(m)+2)` then trims the result string to the length of the original match plus 2 characters (to account for the additional 2 spaces inserted to separate the new second column from the former second, now third, column).
  →   `GFS    8978976`

Comment: thank you for your response. What you have shared, works, but is not there yet. I need to understand how the function works. Can you let me know from the ReformatCol = Left("..... what the code is doing?

Comment: @Andrea See updated answer. For further details see the documentation I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

At first replace by regex pattern `(\d+)\s+([A-Z]+)(\d+)\s+(\w+)` replace with `$1 $2 $3 $4`

and split that by `+`. then ok.

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/nL0cL6/1)